# Fixed navigation bar after scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I am attempting to create a navigation bar that remains fixed only after it has reached the top of the page. I have the code working so that the nav is fixed, but I can't seem to get it to scroll to the top first.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id= "home"> contentcontentcontent </div>
<div id="nav">
    <a href="#home">home</a>
    <a href="#gogreen">go green</a>
    <a href="#yourarea">your area</a>
    <a href="#howto">how to</a></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
nav {
text-align: center;
top: 600;
z-index: 100;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
border: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;}

fixed {
top:600;
z-index: 100;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;}

home {
overflow: hidden;}
```

And the jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function () {
    //console log determines when nav is fixed
    console.log($(window).scrollTop())
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 600) {
        $('#nav').addClass('fixed');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 601) {
        $('#nav').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

These were based off of responses to similar questions on this site, but nothing has seemed to work so far. Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! To get help with questions, you should normally include tags for the language, framework, and context, in addition to (or often instead of) tags like `scrolling`. This is because users are more likely to subscribe to tags like `javascript`, which makes you more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

When writing a CSS selector, ids and classes need to be prefixed by a `#` or a `.` respectively. In your CSS you have

```
nav { // rules }

fixed { // rules }

home { // rules }
```

When you should have

```
#nav { // rules }

.fixed { // rules }

#home { // rules }
```

Here is a fiddle of [your code](http://jsfiddle.net/EJerC/1/) working.